Why can't wrong-owner intention refer to a communal bull?
If someone slaughters a designated-as-pesach animal in the month of (for example) Adar, and has in mind that it should be a pesach, it's invalid, since that's the wrong time to pring a pesach.  However, if one slaughters a pesach animal in Adar and has in mind that it should be a sh'lamim, it's valid as a sh'lamim.
The Bavli, P'sachim 60–61, asks whether this wrong-intention logic applies also to wrong intention for who's bringing it.  Specifically, suppose someone slaughters Person A's pesach in Adar, intending it as Person B's pesach.  Normally, if someone slaughters an animal (actually, sprinkles its blood on the altar, but let's not get into those details now) with the wrong supplicant in mind, the korban is invalid.  But Rav Papa in the g'mara proposes that this one should be valid as a sh'lamim, just like the other wrong-intention case.
Rava refutes this comparison by citing four ways that wrong-supplicant intention is a weaker wrong than wrong-type-of-offering intention is.  One of those ways is that wrong-supplicant intention ruins only an individual's offering, not a communal one, whereas wrong-type-of-offering intention ruins also a communal offering.
On the idea that wrong-supplicant intention does not ruin a communal offering, Rashi explains:

Because for whom would his wrong intention be, that would not be its actual owners?


If the central sanhedrin rules something is permitted, and most of the people follow that ruling, but really it would normally require bringing a chatas if done unintentionally, then not most of the people bring a chatas.  Rather, as Rambam (Sh'gagos 12.1) rules,

each and every tribe brings a bull as a chatas.


So why can't wrong-supplicant intention apply to a communal offering, namely the communal bull?  The one bringing it can have the wrong tribe in mind.

Rabbi Yaakov Yitzchak Ruderman answers:

… according to my explanation [see context there –ed.] that "each tribe is called a community" means each tribe is like all of Israel and its offering is like an offering from all of Israel (for indeed we see that even if one tribe sins all twelve bring a bull apiece), so [the twelve bulls] constitute one big offering from all of Israel, and thus one can't speak of "slaughtering A's offering for B" since A's offering is also B's.

